# Swift Core Data: auto-generating managed object subclass makes the class name to PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME.entityName in model

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm making a purely Swift project, and when I create an entity in model file, then use `Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass` to create class file for the entity, in the model, the `Class` property for entity becomes `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME.entityName`, this will cause core data to fail loading NSManagedObject subclass instance.

I know how to get pass by this by using `@objc()` and rename the class property in model file, but is there any better idea?

Comment: I have the feeling that the "Create NSManagedObject Subclass ..." in Xcode is still broken ... Maybe it should be `${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}.entityName` and should be expanded automatically. Does that work?

Comment: I don't think that you need @objc() *and* a name change in the model file - I think it is one or the other. The fundamental problem us Swift's namespaces - either convert the entities to objective C or prefix their names with the module name.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Replace the `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` with the value of this build setting. By default, it will be the same as your `TARGET_NAME`. The full value in the Class field should be something like `MyApp.entityName`.
2. Use only `entityName` in the Class field and prefix your swift class with `@objc(entityName)`

The `representedClassName` field in the data model appears to be evaluated at runtime so it needs a literal value.